# Deploy incremental database using entity framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, model-view-controller, deployment, publish

I have my first MVC 5 application using entity framework 6. And I want to deploy/publish my database (sql server) but I want to be able to change the database (model and data) easily after that without losing any data.
I found that with enable migration I can do that, but I want to do more automatically and without enable automatic migration because I found that it is unreliable.
Thank you anyway

Comment: so far what you have tried ??any efforts have you put in

Comment: I tried enable migration and enable automatic migration. But I wanted to know if there is another options.